# After my first question I tried to solve the equation $\frac{dT_i}{dt}=\frac{1}{RC}(T_a-T_i)+\frac{1}{C} \Phi_h$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

After my first question I tried to solve my differential equation 
$$\frac{dT_i}{dt}=\frac{1}{RC}(T_a-T_i)+\frac{1}{C} \Phi_h$$
Here is what I have done until now.
I used $y'=b-a \cdot y$ and the solution for this is
$$y=C_1 \cdot e^{-ax}+ \frac{b}{a}.$$
Because of this I just look at
$$\frac{dT_i}{dt}=\frac{1}{RC}(T_a-T_i)=\frac{T_a}{RC}-\frac{1}{RC}T_i(t)$$
$T_i$ is a function of time therefore $T_i(t)$

So I got
$$
\begin{align*}
T_i(t) &=C_1 \cdot e^{\frac{1}{RC}t}+ \frac{T_a/RC}{1/RC} \\
&=C_1 \cdot e^{\frac{1}{RC}t}+ T_a
\end{align*}$$

My book says the answer is 
$$T_i(t)=C_1 \cdot  e^{-\frac{1}{RC}t}+ T_a + R \Phi_h$$

Can someone help me?

Comment: $\Phi_h$ represents warming from a given source

Comment: It is a constant

Answer (score 2):

We are given:

$$\frac{dT_i}{dt}=\frac{1}{RC}(T_a-T_i)+\frac{1}{C} \Phi_h$$

This is a separable equation and separating yields:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{RC}(T_a-T_i)+\frac{1}{C} \Phi_h}~dT_i = \int dt$$

Integrating each side yields:

$$-RC \ln(T_a + \Phi_h R - T_i) = t + k$$

We can re-write this as:

$$ \ln(T_a + \Phi_h R - T_i) = \dfrac{-t + k}{RC}$$

Now, take the exponential of each side and simplify.

Note, the book appears to have used $C$ as the constant, but this can lead to confusion given that is is a capacitor value.

Comment: It is my fault. I should tell you that $C$ is heat capacity. look at change i made

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: No problem, my solution stands as I called it $k$ and you called it $C_1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
b = &\frac{1}{RC}\left(T_a +R\Phi_h\right)&\\
a = &\frac{1}{RC}&
\end{align}
$$
you end up with an equation similar to what you know :) i,e,
$$
y' = b - a\cdot y
$$
that you stated you know above